# java.lang.IllegalAccessException: java.lang.Class<com.xxx.xxxx> is not accessible from java.lang.Class<com.orm.SugarRecord>

Tags: android, sqlite, sugarorm

I am getting IllegalAccessException for the SQL Table which i am created using Sugar ORM. What i am doing is fetching contacts and send it to the server for certain operations then return a value which i am parse using JSON and display. This operation is done by using the service. When i search for the table to get values exception is thrown.

```
private void nonstoprun()
{
    handler = new Handler();
    update = new Runnable()
     {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
         ArrayList<mobstat> musers1 = (ArrayList<mobstat>) mobstat.listAll(mobstat.class); //getting exception here
         setData(musers1);
         handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }

         private void setData(ArrayList<mobstat> musers1)
         {
          musers.clear();
          musers.addAll(musers1);
          descAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
         }
     };
        handler.postDelayed(update, 10);
}
```

getting exception for the line

```
ArrayList<mobstat> musers1 = (ArrayList<mobstat>) mobstat.listAll(mobstat.class);
```

exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: java.lang.Class<com.xxx.xxxx> is not  accessible from java.lang.Class<com.orm.SugarRecord>
```

I am running the code in Android emulator (Nougat)

mobstat class:

```
import com.orm.SugarRecord;
import com.orm.dsl.Unique;
class mobstat extends SugarRecord {
@Unique
String name;
String status;
long stime;

public mobstat(){  }

mobstat(String name, String status, long stime) {
    this.name = name;
    this.status = status;
    this.stime = stime;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return status;
}

String getname(){
    return name;
}
String getstatus(){
    return status;
}
}
```

Comment: can you post the `mobstat` class definition?

Comment: I doubt if the @Unique annotation is a correct one. I think you should first try with removing it. Which version of Sugar do you use?

Answer (score 0):

I know that the question seems to be old, but here we are again ...

The error clearly states that `java.lang.IllegalAccessException`, it means you need to set the **properties** that you are getting/setting or your `init()` i.e constructor on your `SugarRecord` an **access level of `public`**. *So that it can be accessed :)*

It looks like it is private at the moment i.e your `setters & getters` are `private`. (Leaving them **blank** means they are private)

If you are not sure which values are you trying to get or set , it is best that you assign all of your class's getters & setters an access level of `public`

```
class mobstat extends SugarRecord {
      @Unique
      String name;
      String status;
      long stime;
    
      public mobstat(){  }
    
      public mobstat(String name, String status, long stime) {
                this.name = name;
                this.status = status;
                this.stime = stime;
      }
            
                .....
      public String getname(){
                    return name;
      }

}
```

and +1,
It is better if you perform your `<class>.listAll` stuff in the background i.e use an **AsyncTask**,

If you find this useful, then you can reward your self & Play [Sticky Bubble](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fadsel.stickybubble&hl=en_US&gl=US) on Google Play